Module '"@wagmi/core"' has no exported member 'configureChains'
I follow the Wagmi documentation strictly:
import { createConfig, http } from 'wagmi'
import { configureChains } from '@wagmi/core'
import { sepolia, mainnet } from 'wagmi/chains'
import { publicProvider } from '@wagmi/core/providers/public';
import { injected, walletConnect, coinbaseWallet } from 'wagmi/connectors'
import { EthereumClient } from '@web3modal/ethereum'

const projectId = process.env.REACT_APP_WALLET_CONNECT_PROJECT_ID

if (!projectId) {
  throw new Error('You need to provide REACT_APP_WALLET_CONNECT_PROJECT_ID env variable')
}

const { chains, provider, webSocketProvider } = configureChains(
  [mainnet, sepolia],
  [publicProvider()]
)

const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  connectors: [
    injected(),
    walletConnect({ projectId }),
    coinbaseWallet({ appName: 'Your App Name' }),
  ],
  provider,
  webSocketProvider,
})

const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains)

export const config = {
  ...wagmiConfig,
  ethereumClient,
}

Docs:

Getting Module '"@wagmi/core"' has no exported member 'configureChains'.ts(2305) and also Cannot find module '@wagmi/core/providers/public' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307), even though I have @wagmi/core installed.
How should I go about refactoring it? How could i improve my configuration?
